# How to add new instances to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to make a page where a user can enter a url and some text (like an image caption) and when they click the button the url and text will be added to an empty array (which can be accessed by a different script and published on the page). My question is how do I write a function and/or an array for this? What from my code below is wrong and what can I do to fix it? Thanks!

```
<script>           
        var annotatedImageArray = new Array();

        var imageInput = document.getElementById("imageInput");
        var image = imageInput.value;
        var captionInput = document.getElementById("captionInput");
        var caption1 = captionInput.value;
        annotatedImageArray.push({url:image, caption:caption1});
 </script>

<body>
  <input type="text" size="30" id="imageInput" placeholder="Enter URL">
  <input type="text" size="30" id="captionInput" placeholder="Enter Caption">
  <input type="button" value="Add Image" onclick=""/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:
(you can play around with it over here:http://jsfiddle.net/marcelow/NdAkz/)

```
<script>
    (function(window) {
        window['annotatedImageArray'] = [];
        window['addImage'] = function() {
            var imageInput = document.getElementById("imageInput");
            var image = imageInput.value;
            var captionInput = document.getElementById("captionInput");
            var caption1 = captionInput.value;
            annotatedImageArray.push({url:image, caption:caption1});
        }
    })(window);
</script>
<body>
  <input type="text" size="30" id="imageInput" placeholder="Enter URL">
  <input type="text" size="30" id="captionInput" placeholder="Enter Caption">
  <input type="button" value="Add Image" onclick="addImage();"/>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the window and what does it do? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: window is the global context.   

declaring the variable annotatedImageArray and the function addImage inside the window object, is like declaring them globally